# Structured Data for Reocurring Event

Tags: html, microdata, microformats, rdfa, structured-data

I'm the webmaster for smctheatre.com. We're a community theatre that puts on a handful of plays each year. I'm adding to my toolbox with learning structured data. Microformat, microdata, or RDFa, I don't have any strong preference for one over another. I do like the syntax of RDFa Lite and microfomat over microdata and full-blown RDFa.

The only thing I haven't been able to get an answer to is how to mark up an event that occurs on multiple dates, and sometimes at different times.

Here's a trimmed down snippet from the site:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Play Name</h1>
    <div class="addthis_toolbox">...</div>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <h2>Dates</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>May</li>
      <li>Fridays 17 &amp; 24</li>
      <li>Saturdays 18 &amp; 25</li>
      <li>Sundays 19 &amp; 26</li>
      <li>Monday 27</li>
      <li>All shows start at 7:30 PM</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Tickets</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Adult $8.00</li>
      <li>Child (5-17) $5.00</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Directed By</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Director Name</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div>
    <p>Summary of a theatre play....</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Duration of plays are typically two hours, but given that these are live performances, there's no hard and fast ending time.

How do I mark up the content to indicate the dates and times?

Answer (score 1):

Seriously doubt there's an example of exactly what you want, but microformats are flexible and I think I've found enough to get you started:

```
<div class="vevent">
 <a class="url" href="http://conferences.oreillynet.com/pub/w/40/program.html">
  http://conferences.oreillynet.com/pub/w/40/program.html
 </a>
 <span class="summary">Web 2.0 Conference</span>: 
 <abbr class="dtstart" title="2005-10-05">October 5</abbr>-
 <abbr class="dtend" title="2005-10-07">7</abbr>,
 at the <span class="location">Argent Hotel, San Francisco, CA</span>
</div>
```

The example below uses multiple dates at the same venue; swap out the `div` for your `article` and looks like you're in business. easily make your header the summary, and put the description class on your `p` for summary...even though that sounds backwards, it's what you want.

How much further you want to take it is really up to you. I see where you could work start times, possibly a url....and also more microformats, to get even more goodness out of them. You should check out the wiki, it's full of great info, and examples from which you can and should pilfer.

http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar